# Ruby on Rails - Testing changes to Capistrano's deploy.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, deployment

I'm trying to test some changes out on production without having to commit and push the changes because I only want to commit what actually works. The project I'm working on was created with Rails (3.0.2), and deploys with Capistrano (3.1). I've tried making changes in the root folder of my app and redeploying, and the changes are not reflected on the website. I've tried making changes in the `root/current` directory and redeploying and that didn't work.

Is there any way I can redeploy changes to the server without having to push it to Github first?

Comment: Why would you want to test untested code in *production*?! That's what the development and test (and whatever custom environments you have) are for, or running the production environment locally--but be aware this can have unintended consequences if you're accessing production data.

Comment: Your best bet is launching `production` environment locally. Deployment fetches code from version control by design, it is assumed stable, and you don't want to deploy unstable changes to production.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Essentially, the change I'm making is something that gets done when the app is deployed to production. I'm not sure how I would test that otherwise. But I will take your and D-side's advice and find another way. Thank you!

Comment: like @DaveNewton mentioned, you need to be hacking away at a development or staging environment and have a rails server running on a localhost port so you can see the changes before pushing to your version control. Default rails s opens port localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can redeploy changes to the server without having
>   to push it to Github first?

No this isn't possible since one of the first things that Capistrano will do is `git clone` the latest from whatever branch you've specified in your deploy config.

I'm not sure what your familiarity with Rails is but the proper way to do this would be to create a new *staging* environment and deploy to that. The staging environment would have similar settings to your production environment with a separate database so that you don't affect production data.

Capistrano 3 supports this flow out of the box so that once you've set everything up you can simply call

```
cap staging deploy
```

to deploy to the staging environment, and

```
cap production deploy
```

to deploy to the production environment.

Comment: We have a development environment. I'm making a slight tweak in `config/deploy.rb` though, I assumed that the only way to test it was to deploy to production. So I'm guessing I could do something like `cap development deploy`, right?

Comment: As long you have a corresponding `development.rb` config file under `config/deploy` then yeah that should work.